# use copied library in another project

Tags: node.js, electron, axios

I'm new to Electron and Node.js and now I learn Electron from video tutorials. In the tutorial the guy installs axios with `npm install axios --save` and then imports it with `const axios = require('axios')`. The problem is I'm behind proxy at my work so installing packages with NPM is quite problematic. But I already have **axios** in my another project. So I just copied it and pasted to node_modules of my current tutorial project. But it seems like `const axios = require('axios')` doesn't work in it. How do use that copied axios in my current project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) has a lot of devDependencies. Those do not get installed when you just copy it. I'd suggest duplicating your existing project (assuming it works there).

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bundlesize": "^0.17.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-eslint": "^20.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.13.3",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.19",
    "grunt-webpack": "^1.0.18",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-ajax": "^0.1.13",
    "karma-opera-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "sinon": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1",
    "url-search-params": "^0.10.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
},
```